# Total work needed to move an object along a path under the the force field $\vec F = (4y^3-3xy^2, 3x+12y^2x-3x^2y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Hello I am getting stuck on this question:

> 7. The total work needed to move an object along a path of straight lines from $(-1,0)$ to $(0, a)$ and from $(0, a)$ to $(1,0)$, $a>0$, $a\in \mathbb R$, under the force field $\vec F = (4y^3-3xy^2, 3x+12y^2x-3x^2y)$ is equal $3$, if the value of constant $a$ is:
>      (A) $1$;
>      (B) $2$;
>      (C) $3$;
>      (D) $4$;
>      (E) none of the above.

I am unsure of whether or not I am supposed to use the fundamental theorem for line integrals to evaluate this, which would result in the $a$ being irrelevant, or if there is another way to do this problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try parametrizing the integral. Break it into two smaller integrals. Let x=t-1, y=at, then for the second integral, let y=at, x=1-t

Comment: Note that $curl\ F \neq 0$, hence we cannot conclude that the paths chosen are irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know if this helps simplify the calculations, but if you subtract $(0,3x)$ from $F$, then the force becomes conservative. So you could break the calculation into a conservative part, where you just need to find the potential, and a non-conservative part whose form is simpler than in the original problem.

Comment: Please don't post low-quality images. Please type out all images. Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bf F$ is the sum of two vector fields:
${\bf F}_1=(0,3x)$ (which is not conservative) and ${\bf F}_2=(4y^3-3xy^2,12y^2x-3x^2y)$ (which is conservative with potential function $U(x,y)=4xy^3-\frac{3x^2y^2}{2}$). The work for ${\bf F}_2$ does not depend on $a$ and it is equal to $U(1,0)-U(-1,0)=0$. On the other hand, the work for ${\bf F}_1$ does depend on $a$ and it can be evaluated by computing the (easy) line integral along the straight lines from $(−1,0)$ to $(0,a)$ and from $(0,a)$ to $(1,0)$.

Comment: Very nice comment to calculate it quite easily!

Comment: Ok this is the field I was getting, but I'm not sure on what to put for the bounds. I assume F2 is just F(1,0) - F(-1,0), but what is it for F1?

Comment: @AusitinEvan98 For ${\bf F}_1$, calculate the line integral!

Comment: ok, thanks for the help!